# Explaining why planets are round

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets, variational-principle, variational-calculus

is it possible to prove that planets (and/or stars) are always round (elliptical if you consider the spin)? Is there a set of equation that demonstrate that fluids (after all, molten rocks "floating" in outer space is that...) tend to form spheres? Maybe theres a way to prove that they can't exist (in a stable condition) in another shape?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_planet

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107584/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The minimum (gravitational) energy configuration for a drop of molten rock corresponds to a spherical shape.