# How to prove that a sphere has the minimum gravitational potential energy for a given volume of uniformly dense material?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, variational-principle, variational-calculus

Planets are spherical (roughly) in shape because a spherical configuration gives the minimum gravitational potential energy.

How does one prove that the sphere is the shape that gives minimum gravitational potential energy for a volume of uniformly dense material?

Comment: Mathematicians: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261932086_A_Round_Ball_Uniquely_Minimizes_Gravitational_Potential_Energy Physicists: “It’s obvious!” :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107584/2451