# What's the minimum possible size of a round astronomical body?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, material-science, planets, geophysics

What's the minimum possible size of a spherical shaped rocky [planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet) or satellite? Is it possible to occur a spherical shaped planet without having a molten core?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555769/2451 , https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/9745 and links therein.

Comment: The official international definition of ‘planet’, or do you just want a round something in orbit around something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimum radius of a celestial body that allows gravity to transform the body into a globe is informally called the [potato radius](https://sketchplanations.com/the-potato-radius). Empirical evidence suggests it is about 200-300 km, depending on the composition of the body - the higher the proportion of rock to ice, the larger the potato radius.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the source of heat:  the kinetic energy of in-falling material or radioactivity. It has to get hot enough to flow under the action of gravity.

Comment: For that matter,  molten ejecta could conceivably go  near-spherical before cooling to a solid object in a zero-g environment.