# Shapes of planets?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets

I was wondering if there was a general explanation as to why it is that all the planets we observe are roughly spherical, and never flat/planar like galaxies.

Could there potentially be flat or planar planets?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107584/2451 and links therein. (Also note that a planet [_by definition_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet) is rounded by its own gravity.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are stars, planets and larger moons (approximately) spherical in shape (like, the Sun, the Moon, the Earth, and other planets)?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26297/)

Comment: I don't see why this question is a duplicate of other two questions. None of the other two questions answer why galaxies are more "flat" than spherical (and what is the precise point of difference between planets and galaxies). After all, just like planets, galaxies too are structures which are shaped by their own gravitation.