# Why is Earth a sphere?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry, planets

Physicists and Physics enthusiasts . I am new to this platform. And I wanted to post a question . Since I have nothing in my mind. I wanted to ask , ***Why is the earth a sphere and not other shape?***

Moreover please provide me some books where I can learn physics. I am in my senior year in  high school i.e 12th Standard

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26297/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107584/2451 and links therein.